# Restrict children block elements to parent box fixed boundary?

Tags: css, html, display

This has become a serious thorn in my side and could use another pair of eyes.

Scenario is as shown in the snippet where as the `div1` and `div2` are expected to respect the boundary of `div0` however it seems that `div2` (the red outline) doesn't respect the boundary of the parent that I expect to contain it and invoke the overflow scrolling.

Example of the issue;

```css
div { box-sizing: border-box; }

#div0 {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  border: lime 5px solid;
}

#div1 {
  border: blue 2px dashed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#div2 {
  margin: .75rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: red 15px solid;
  background-color: rgba(244, 66, 66, .3);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div0">
  <div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
      <p>Where</p>
      <p>is</p>
      <p>the</p>
      <p>scroll</p>
      <p>bar?</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the div2 is overflowing so overflow:auto should be on the parent element not the overflowing element

Comment: @TemaniAfif Unfortunately in this scenario I really need the div2 to have the overflow. Ideally I would expect the margin on div2 to be consistent and respect the parent like the div1 (the blue dashed line) does.

Comment: so you need to add height:100% ... and if you want margin make if calc(100% - 2*margin)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Is it possible to not have `div2` always take that height and instead have the calc act as max-height? So `div2` can be auto height until it reaches the calc max-height before scroll is invoked? I keep trying various combinations of `height` and `max-height` but have been so far unsuccessful. There has to be a trick I'm forgetting....

Comment: yes, the max-height will do the trick if you keep the height:100% defined on the parent element.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I try that and it goes back to original issue. Haha I can't tell you how much of a pain this instance has become...

Comment: you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/6jvd2yr1/?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh man you're getting me so much closer!! Thank you! I just have to get this to a point it works until I can refactor the stuff above that's really keeping standard box model at bay. Could I trouble with [one more scenario](https://jsfiddle.net/dfxm10ew/) if `div2` is parent to three more additional block elements and I'd want `main` to scroll?

Comment: add some flexbox inside ;) https://jsfiddle.net/cs8z3ekn/

Comment: @TemaniAfif as per usual I owe you lunch or something bro. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Give your `div2` the same height as the parent and then set `overflow-y` auto on child container and it'd work. Here's what I tried, please check this: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1HU09CDQGNA)

Answer (score -1):

If you set to `div2` the `height: 100%` and remove its `margin` then that solves your problem.

Edited.

Comment: *It should work*, If you are not sure whether your solution's going to work or not then don't post answer. Stick to comments.